# rails calling a class method based on the value of instance attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So i need to basically call a class method that defines some methods and a relationship, but need to pass a different parameter based on an attribute of the instances of this class, so different instances get different methods.

I need to do it like this because we are working with a legacy database.

what i got:

```
after_find do |instance|
  group_id = case instance.finance_object_type
    when 'E' then 281
    when 'A' then 282
    when 'K' then 283
    else ''
  end
  self.class.keyword_attribute :leistung_code, group_id: group_id
end
```

This works, the keyword_attribute method generates the proper methods and relationships.

The only issue is that if you load `instance_1`, then immediately load `instance_2` with a different `finance_object_type`, the generated methods for `instance_1` get overwritten as well.

Is there another way to do this?

keyword_attribute:

```
def keyword_attribute(name, **options)
  foreign_key = options[:foreign_key] || name
  group_id    = options[:group_id]

  unless name.is_a?(Symbol)
    fail 'A name is required for the keyword_attribute'
  end

  unless group_id.is_a?(Integer)
    fail 'A group_id is required for the keyword_attribute'
  end

  self.belongs_to name,
    -> () { group_id ? where(keyword_group_id: group_id) : where },
    foreign_key: foreign_key,
    primary_key: 'stichwort',
    class_name:  'Keyword'

  define_method("#{name}=") do |keyword|
    if keyword.is_a?(String)
      keyword =
        if group_id
          Keyword.where(keyword_group_id: group_id)
        else
          Keyword
        end.find_by!(code: keyword)
    end

    super(keyword)
  end

  define_method("#{name}_id") do
    if read_attribute(foreign_key).present?
      "#{group_id}:#{read_attribute(foreign_key)}"
    end
  end

  define_method("#{name}_id=") do |primary_key|
    if primary_key.present?
      if primary_key&.match(":")
        _, keyword = primary_key.split(':')
      else
        keyword = Keyword.find(primary_key)&.code
      end
    else
      keyword = nil
    end
    send("#{name}=", keyword)
  end
end
```

update: I'm trying this with singleton_class, this works for the generated methods. But not for the belongs_to, possibly due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893682/overwriting-adding-an-activerecord-association-dynamically-using-a-singleton-cla)

here's the updated situation:

```
after_find do
  group_id = case finance_object_type
    when 'E' then 281
    when 'A' then 282
    when 'K' then 283
  end
  singleton_class.keyword_attribute :leistung_code, group_id: group_id
end
```

Comment: Can you please also post the code for `keyword_attribute`?

Comment: added the `keyword_attribute` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'r patching your class at runtime. This is not restricted to a single object. This will change all new objects of your class. You can try to extend only the new object for instance with:

```
instance.define_singleton_method("#{name}_id") do
  if read_attribute(foreign_key).present?
     "#{group_id}:#{read_attribute(foreign_key)}"
   end
end
```

Or with

```
instance.extend(ModuleWithNeededMethods)
```

How to combine this with the `belongs_to` definition I can't say at the moment.

But I think you should try another approach and take a look at Single Table Inheritance. `finance_object_type` looks like a type column for STI.

Comment: implemented `singleton_class` like you suggested, and this works except for the `belongs_to` (like you said).

i'm gonna try if the STI idea works for my situation

Comment: STI has worked for me and there were some more flags for STI that I didn't show here, thanks for the input!